# How to Change Default URL in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have one default route in my `routeconfig.cs` file

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It will hide `Home/Index` as Url in browser. My target is to display `localhost:44300/Login` instead of `localhost:44300/Home/Index` (but internally it will call `Home/Index`) and I want to hide `Home/Details` action method as url

Comment: defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your default route to `Account` controller and to your necessary `Action` method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id =   
            UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Update:**

It is not possible as MVC has a convention that **[RouteTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable(v=vs.110).aspx)** should be look like that:
`controller/action` or vice versa.

If you exclude controller from the route, you'll get an exception:

> The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which
>   is required.